# By using two arrays generate missing values count +php

Tags: php, arrays

I have My First Array like the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => E
    [5] => F
    [6] => G
    [7] => H
    [8] => J
)
```

Second Array Like

```
case 1:

Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [7] => H
    [8] => J
)

case2:
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [5] => F
    [6] => G
    [7] => H
    [8] => J
)

case3:

   Array
   (
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [5] => F
    [6] => G
   )
```

Now i want to compare These two arrays and if the value from first array is in second array i want count 1 and so on..finally I want output as

```
case1 OP:
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 2
)

case2 OP:
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 2
)

case3 OP:
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 0
)
```

case1 Logic:

```
A  B    C  D  E  F  G    H  J
|  |                     |  |
A  B                     H  J
|  |                     |  |   
1  1                     1  1
  2           0            2
```

case2 Logic:

```
A  B     C  D  E  F  G     H  J
|  |     |  |  |  |  |     |  |
A  B     C  D     F  G     H  J
|  |     |  |  |  |  |     |  |   
1  1     1  1  0  1  1     1  1
  2             4            2
```

case3 Logic:

```
A  B     C  D  E  F  G     H  J
|  |     |  |  |  |  |     |  |
         C  D     F  G       
|  |     |  |  |  |  |     |  |   
0  0     1  1  0  1  1     0  0
  0             4            0
```

Please tell the logic for that...thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please tell *us* the logic for that first. I don't know how you'd arrive at the result "2, 0, 2" here.

Comment: How did you arrive at that final output? Any insight will help

Comment: if A and B matching then count as 2 and C,D,E,F,G not matching then count as 0 and H and J matching then count As 2 @decez

Comment: if A and B matching then count as 2 and C,D,E,F,G not matching then count as 0 and H and J matching then count As 2 @Hanky 웃 Panky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$array1 = range('A', 'I');
$array2 = array(0 => 'A', 1 => 'B', 7 => 'H', 8 => 'I');

$result = array();

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    // if value matches ...
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array2) && $array2[$key] === $value) {
        // if last result was not positive ...
        if (!end($result)) {
            // ... add positive result
            $result[] = 1;
        } else {
            // ... else increment positive result
            $result[count($result) - 1]++;
        }
    // ... else if last result was not negative ...
    } else if (end($result) !== 0) {
        // ... add negative result
        $result[] = 0;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => int(2)
  [1] => int(0)
  [2] => int(2)
}
```

---

The above was based on the assumption that *consecutive matches* should be counted up and non-matches should be represented by `0`. I.e., 2, 0, 2 means *"two matches, any number of non-matches, two matches"*.

Since *apparently* (this is still not clearly stated anywhere) the logic is actually based on seating groups in a plane and simply a count of taken seats in each seating group, the logic is much simpler:

```
<?php

$seats = [
    ['A', 'B'],
    ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    ['H', 'J']
];

$reservations = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J'];

$result = [];

foreach ($seats as $group) {
    $result[] = count(array_intersect($group, $reservations));
}

print_r($result);
```

You need to define your groups somewhere, in this case it's explicitly done using the `$seats` variable. The counting of matches per group is then pretty trivial.

Comment: Please do your own needful, we are not a free coding service here. I think I have shown quite simply how to express this kind of simple logic, base your own work off of that.

Comment: sorry to disturb you..above logic is working only for case 1. that's why i asked you deceze

Comment: Yes, it is indeed, because your other cases seem to have an entirely different logic.

Comment: Same Logic..but I don't have Any C D E F G in middle..that's the count As 0..but in my second case i have  C D F G then I want count as 4..

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. You have groups A-D and F-J, so 4, 0, 4. Why is the middle group a 4 even though it has a 0 in its center? If that was somehow implied in the original question you seriously need to do a better job of explaining the thinking behind your logic.

Comment: Actually Here I have 3 groups..A-B , C-G and H-J. Based On these 3 groups i want count of individual group in new array

Comment: What is the logic behind having three groups? Where is this apparent? How did these three groups come to be?

Comment: actually the logic needs to implement flight reservation system..those groups are seat groups..

Comment: Go back to the drawing board with what you're doing here. These groups won't be fixed either as 2-5-2, they'll differ based on different plane types, or at least the algorithm needs to accommodate that possibility. And I still have no idea what the goal is with this exercise.

Comment: Wow..awesome..looking like very experienced..!..means the logic get changed if i have 2-4-2?please clarify me..!

Comment: anyway can you please tell me the logic to reach 2-5-2

Comment: See update. You *really* need to state what you want more clearly, just guessing based on vague examples is not the way to tackle a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Logic
    Loop Through for array 1
         :Loop Through Array 2
           :COMPARE Arry[i] to Array[0....N-1]
                Increment if equal







 <?php
    $arr=array("A","B","C","D","E","F");
    $arr2=array("A","B","C","C");
    $arr3;
    $i=0;
    $x=0;
    foreach ($arr as &$value) {
        $x=0;
        foreach($arr2 as &$value1){
            if(($value==$value1))
            {
                echo $value ."+++". $value1 ."</br>";
                $x=$x+1;
                $arr3[$i]= $x;

            }
    $i++;
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: 1) The key and the value have to match according to the OP. 2) You're never incrementing `$i`, so can never produce the expected result.

Comment: 1. I thought he only want to compare the values. 2. forget to copy full code

Answer (score 0):

```
$size1 = count($array1);
$size2 = count($array2);
$hit = 0;
$miss = -1;
$max_size = max($size1, $size2);
$array3 = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $max_size ;$i++)
{ 
  $flag = 0;
  if(isset($array1[$i]) && isset($array2[$i]))
  {   
    if($array1[$i] === $array2[$i])
    {
      $hit++;
      $miss = -1;
    }
    else
      $flag = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    $flag = 1;
  }
  if($flag == 1)
  {
    if($miss == -1)
    {
      if($hit > 0)
        array_push($array3, $hit);
      $miss = 0;
      array_push($array3, 0);
   }
   $hit = 0;
  }
}
if($hit > 0)
  array_push($array3, $hit);
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Yeah, you can really only *hope*. I don't *think* this works as a generalised solution, but honestly it's so complicated, I don't even want to invest the energy to prove it.

Comment: I tested it and I believe that this code works as a generalized solution. And this is not as complicated as you think.

Comment: It doesn't even work for the OP's given case, and it throws errors: http://3v4l.org/nC0OV

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I totally forgot that in PHP array indices can be skipped. My code won't work for that case.

Comment: I have edited the code to work in a more generalised way. Those flags are to optimize the number of iterations.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an answer:

```
#To store the final array values
$final = array();
$i=0;
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val){
    #On each loop, check if value from first array exists in second
    $arr2_key = array_search($val,$arr2);
    if($arr2_key!==FALSE && $arr2_key==$key){

         /*
            If exists:
               Check if it isn't the first value and if the previous value
               is not 0.
               This is the case when we already have checked till 'G'
               so at this point out $final array will have:
                     [0]=>2
                     [1]=>0 (this 0 from elseif part explained later)
               Now, currently 'H' exists so we need to increment the 
               index of $final.
        */
        ($i!=0 && $final[$i-1]!=0)?$i++:'';

        /*  Incrementing count value, when A found will be 1, when B
            found, will be 2.
        */
        $final[$i] = (isset($final[$i]))?$final[$i]+1:1;
    }
    elseif(isset($final[$i]) && $final[$i]!=0)
    {
        /* If value does not exist in second array, 
           increment the index and save it as 0.
           This will occur only once till a new value is found.
        */
        $i++;
        $final[$i] = 0;
    }
    elseif($i==0)
    {
        /* 
           After some testing, found that if the first value 
           is not found, it won't count it, so this block checks that
           and does the necessary.
        */
            $final[$i] = 0;
            $i++;
     }
}
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/140167)**

Comment: According to the OP, the key and the value have to match, not just the value.

Comment: @user Try this with `array(0 => 'A', 1 => 'B', 3 => 'H', 4 => 'I')` as your second array (notice the differing keys) and see that it does not work as you expect.

Comment: @deceze On second look, the OP hasn't explicitly stated anything about the keys, probably the reason I missed it. Fixed.

Comment: your logic fulfills only my case1 requirement @Cheezburger

Comment: @Olivia Your logic is not clear. Can you put in more cases? Like what if your second array has A,C,E,G,J - what should it show then?